# ffmpeg - converting pngs with white background to movie give black background

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a list of files with their names in the form [1-1000].00.png.
All these are flattened images (graphs) with white background color.
I am trying to make a movie out of these files using ffmpeg. However, when I use ffmpeg, everything white in the images become black in the movie. And everything black remains the same. The command I used is:

The command I use is:

> ffmpeg -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 8 -f image2 -pattern_type glob -i
>   '*.00.png' movie.mp4

Answer (score 3):

are you sure the images have a white background? maybe they have a transparent background. normally transparent backgrounds will converted to black in a file format without transparency supported.

but you can also try this:

you can add a white background to your video file with the `-filter_complex` parameter and a second `-i` input of a white colored image file in the same pixel size as your graphs.

```
-filter_complex "[0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [graphs]; [1:v][graphs] overlay=shortest=1 [out]" -map "[out]"
```

`[0:v]` is your first video source, your graphs. `[1:v]` is your second video
source, your white colored image. `[name]` this is always a placeholder name to tell the filter_complex what you want to use in the next step. `;` delimters an action.

Comment: I used mogrify to make sure they have a white background. Also used convert. Neither helped.
Btw, what should I use in place of [graphs] and [out](movie.mp4?)?

Comment: `ffmpeg -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 8 -f image2 -pattern_type glob -i '*.00.png' -i 'white.png' -filter_complex "[0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [graphs]; [1:v][graphs] overlay=shortest=1 [out]" -map "[out]" movie.mp4` should do it. `[graphs]` is just a placeholder name.

Comment: It does nothing. It creates an 8 kb file which has only the first of the images.

Comment: you are right, for some reason ffmpeg drops a lot of frames. i guess is because of the single white frame. i tried a bit find this better solution: `ffmpeg -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 8 -f image2 -i "name.%04d.00.png" -filter_complex "color=size=1920x1080:color=white [white]; [white][0:v] overlay=shortest=1 [out]" -map "[out]" movie.mp4`. as you can see i replaced the white input with a white solid in the filter complex.

Comment: It still has the background problem. I created a gif file from the png files. It was fine. But when I tried to convert the gif, the background became black again. I think some library should be missing. It is highly probable as only ffmpeg is installed here (in the lab system, not at home).